# Get screenshot of failed tests from Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci, behat

For local I know how to download the failed tests screenshots.

```
scp -P 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1:/tmp/features_article_feature_817.png ~/Downloads/.
```

How do we download the screenshot from travis CI ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For people who get here via Google, there is an alternative approach.

You can run a (failing) job/build in debug mode, which gives you access to an interactive session via ssh. See the [Travis docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/running-build-in-debug-mode/) for more information on how to.

Once in your interactive environment, you can run your [build phases](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/running-build-in-debug-mode/#convenience-bash-functions) and find info on failing specs in your `tmp` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really ssh to Travis CI. What you can do is to upload your build artifacts (like screenshots) to Amazon S3. Here's an example config that would result in uploading all png files found in the /tmp directory:

```
# .travis.yml

addons:
  artifacts: true
  paths:
    - $(ls /tmp/*.png | tr "\n" ":")
```

You'll also have to configure some Amazon specific environment variables:

```
ARTIFACTS_KEY=(AWS access key id)
ARTIFACTS_SECRET=(AWS secret access key)
ARTIFACTS_BUCKET=(S3 bucket name)
```

Environment variables can be [encrypted and securely defined](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-encrypted-variables-in-.travis.yml) in your `.travis.yml` with the travis tool.

Read more about amazon s3 uploader and secure variables in Travis CI docs:

- https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/
- https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-encrypted-variables-in-.travis.yml

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of an error in the yaml here - `paths` should be indented under `artifacts`. The .travis.yml fiel would have

```
# .travis.yml

addons:
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $(ls /tmp/*.png | tr "\n" ":")
```